# Not able to view all columns in Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to output all columns of a data frame .

Here is the code below:

```
df_advertiser_activity_part_qa  = df_advertiser_activity_part.loc[(df_advertiser_activity_part['advertiser_id']==209988 )]
df_advertiser_activity_part_qa.sort(columns ='date_each_day_et')

df_advertiser_activity_part_qa
```

when I output the data frame not all columns gets displayed . This has 21 columns and between some columns there is just there dots "..." I am using ipython notebook . Is there a way by  which this can be ignored.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

try:

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

but depending how many columns you have this is not a good idea. The data is being abbreviated because you have too many columns to fit practically on the screen.

You might be better off saving to a `.csv` to inspect the data.

```
df.to_csv('myfile.csv')
```

or if you have lots of rows:

```
df.head(1000).to_csv('myfile.csv')
```