# Unable to access all the columns in pandas DataFrame where data is imported from kdb+ using qPython

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kdb

I am importing data from a keyed table in Kdb+ to a pandas DataFrame using qPython library. If I run a synchronous query

```
    x=q.sync('select from prod where ID=9 ')
```

Then x is of type `qpython.qcollection.QKeyedTable`. But if I make `numpy_temporals=true`the return type is pandas DataFrame.

```
    from qpython import qconnection
    with qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5000) as q:
    query = 'select from table where ID=5'
    x=q.sync(query, numpy_temporals = True)
    print x.iloc[0:3,0:3]
    print x.columns.values
```

x.iloc[0:1,0:1] returns

```
EMP_ID   PROD_ID   month   total   x 
01        02       jan-17    5.5   6
```

x.columns.values returns

```
['month' 'total' 'x']
```

The data is from a keyed table,  the DataFrame is unable to access the primary key fields. The table has 5 fields but the returned data frame shows only 3. I am unable to access the first two columns.

I have looked at the following stackoverflow questions [Not able to view all columns in Pandas Data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775813/not-able-to-view-all-columns-in-pandas-data-frame), [Python pandas, how to widen output display to see more columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-how-to-widen-output-display-to-see-more-columns) but they do not solve the problem.

Also I want to read the data from the DataFrame into a class `Employee`, so as to create a feature vector for each employee. I do not want the data to be stored in a DataFrame as certain features will be multi-valued like `organization`(the employee might work part-time in multiple organizations).

Am I doing it correctly or is there a better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at a keyed table - the conversion to a pandas DataFrame makes the keys the indexes for the table -

Q process

```
q)\p 5000
q)t:([a:til 10;b:reverse til 10]c:10?`3;d:10?10i)
```

Python process

```
> import pandas as pd
> import numpy as np
> from qpython.qconnection import QConnection as qc
> q = qc('localhost', 5000)
> q.open()
> x = q.sync('select from t', pandas=True)
> x.columns.values
array(['c', 'd'], dtype=object)
> x.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
       labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]],
       names=[u'a', u'b'])
```

If you wish to view all your columns as a standard DataFrame, with no indexes (other than standard i-indexing), amend your query to

```
> x = q.sync('0!select from t', pandas=True)
```

Note the unkeying performed by the `0!`.

```
> x.columns.values
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype=object)
```

It is worth reading the [qpython documentation](http://qpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html#data-conversions), as it does cover this.